# Spacing around inline equations

Tags: math-mode, spacing, inline

What is the parameter determining spacing and stretchability around inline equations? I want to tweak spacing exactly but cannot find where the parameters are.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel and `\m@th` does what??? :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the parameter is `\mathsurround` but it is usually 0pt, but you can use

```
\setlength\mathsurround{2cm}
```

to space things out a bit

Comment: Interesting. Are there any drawbacks of changing this length? Is it advisable?

Comment: Indeed. I missed that ;-)

Comment: It should be noted that `\mathsurround` has no flexibility (it's a kern, rather than a skip).

Comment: @egreg, true, which always seems like a slightly strange choice, limits the usefulness (and as far as I can see it's almost never used)