# Vertical bar strangely moving in a complex block matrix macro (XeTeX or pdfTeX)

Tags: arrays

The following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\sq}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
\DeclareSymbolFont{bbold}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbbold}{bbold}
\newcommand{\blocks}[9][-10]{\!\!\begin{array}{cccc}%
    #2&#3\hspace{-0.2cm}&%
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{2}{*}{\raisebox{-14pt}{\scalebox{1}[1.3]{\Huge{$\vert$}}}%
    \hspace{0.2cm}\raisebox{#1pt}{\Huge{$#6$}}}}\\%
    #4&#5\hspace{-0.2cm}\\[0.2em]%
    \hline\multicolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{2}{*}{\raisebox{#9pt}{\Huge{$#7$}\hspace{-0.2cm}}}}&%
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{2}{*}{\raisebox{-5pt}{\scalebox{1}[1]{\Huge{$\vert$}}}%
    \hspace{0.2cm}\raisebox{#9pt}{\Huge{$#8$}}}}\\\\%
    \end{array}\!\!}

\begin{document}
$$\sq{\blocks[-13]{\cosh\theta_v}{-\sinh\theta_v}{\sinh\theta_v}{\cosh\theta_v}
    {\mathbbold{0}}{\mathbbold{0}\quad\,\,\,}{\mathbbold{1}}{-7}}.$$
$$\sq{\blocks[-13]{\cosh\theta_v}{-\sinh\theta_v}{\sinh\theta_v}{\cosh\theta_v}
    {\mathbbold{0}}{\mathbbold{0}\quad\,\,\,}{\mathbbold{1}}{1}}.$$
\end{document}
```

typesets to:

[image]

Why does that vertical bar on the "second" row move down as the multicolumn-multirows of that row move up? And why does this macro, with `cc|cc` in the array definition, create a vertical line that stops at the `\hline` and doesn't go below it?

Comment: It's quite hard to follow what those macros are supposed to do. They seem to be *ad hoc* for that problem; do you mind if I show a completely different realization?

Comment: OK go ahead, try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd never use a macro with nine arguments.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% Let's go all the way and define \mathbbold at every size
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{bbold}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
   {  <-5.5> bbold5 <5.5-6.5> bbold6 <6.5-7.5> bbold7
      <7.5-8.5> bbold8 <8.5-9.5> bbold9 <9.5-11> bbold10
      <11-15> bbold12 <15-> bbold17 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{bbold}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbbold}{bbold}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\bigblock}[2][\Huge]{%
  \mkern9mu
  \vcenter{\kern.3ex\hbox{#1$\m@th\mathstrut\mathbbold{#2}$}}%
  \mkern9mu
}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{arblock}[1]
  {\begin{array}{@{}#1@{}}}
  {\end{array}}


\begin{document}

\[
\left[\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
\begin{arblock}{cc}
\cosh\theta_v & -\sinh\theta_v \\
\sinh\theta_v & \cosh\theta_v
\end{arblock}
  & \bigblock{0} \\
\hline
  \bigblock{0} & \bigblock{1}
\end{array}\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The command `\bigblock` has an optional argument, default value `\Huge`; you can use `\bigblock[\Large]{0}` or even `\bigblock[\fontsize{54}{0}\selectfont]{0}` if you want an extralarge symbol.

Comment: Seems fine. What do `\mkern9mu`, `\kern.3ex`, `\m@th`, `\mathstrut` and `@{}` do?

Comment: @MickG `\mkern9mu` is to give a bit more room to the big numbers; `\kern.3ex` to lower them a bit; `\m@th` for avoiding possible interaction with `mathsurround`, `\mathstrut` inserts an invisible character as high and deep as a parenthesis; `@{}` removes the padding space before or after a column in `array` or `tabular`.

Comment: And what is `mathsurround`?

Comment: @MickG See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149694/spacing-around-inline-equations