# How to add space around all inline equations, adjusting for punctuation

Tags: spacing

The answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149694/spacing-around-inline-equations) explains how to add space around inline equations, but it doesn't account for punctuation. You can see what I mean in the picture below.

[image]

Is there a way to put the space after the comma, rather than before it? The obvious solution of putting the comma inside the equation environment, e.g., `$A = \pi r^2,$` won't work because the fonts are different (I'm using XeLaTeX). That is, unless you manually specify each time that the comma should be  a different font, but I'm hoping for a lazier solution (which accounts for all of the normal punctuation: periods, commas, semicolons, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

If you use a non zero value for `\mathsurround`, you should add punctuation inside the formula and then restore the spacefactor afterwards.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\fp}[1]{%
  \mbox{#1\xdef\fpsf{\the\spacefactor}}%
  \aftergroup\setfpsf
}
\newcommand\setfpsf{\spacefactor\fpsf\relax}

\begin{document}

The area of a circle is given by $A=\pi r^2$, where $r$ is its radius.
The length of the circumference is $C=2\pi r$. Easy.

\mathsurround=6pt \xspaceskip=10pt

The area of a circle is given by $A=\pi r^2$, where $r$ is its radius.
The length of the circumference is $C=2\pi r$. Easy.

The area of a circle is given by $A=\pi r^2,$ where $r$ is its radius.
The length of the circumference is $C=2\pi r.$ Easy.

The area of a circle is given by $A=\pi r^2\fp{,}$ where $r$ is its radius.
The length of the circumference is $C=2\pi r\fp{.}$ Easy.

\end{document}
```

Here the settings are exaggerated by the high `\xspaceskip`, used just for testing that the additional space is inserted when appropriate (fourth paragraph).

[image]

Here's the output of

```
The area of a circle is given by $A=\pi r^2\fp{,}$ where $r$ is its radius.
The length of the circumference is $C=2\pi r\fp{.}$ Easy.
```

when `\mathsurround=3pt` is used:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This answer seems not to be true if you use XeLaTeX.

I dont see your problem.
This

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
The Area $A$ of a circle is given by $A=\pi r^2$, where $r$ is the radius.
\end{document}
```

results in:
[image]
which is absolutly fine.

Comment: I'm using XeLaTeX and the body font is different from the math font.

Comment: Okay, that information wasn't given in the question, therefore this answer :) I edit my answer accorrding to this.

Answer (score 0):

Although I couldn't reproduce your example without a spurious space inside the `\text` command (see comment), you can use `\kern` (outside mathmode) or `\mkern` (inside mathmode) to fine tune spacing. Note that `\mkern` requires a special unit `mu` rather than your usual `pt`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\text{The area }A\text{ of a circle is given by } A=\pi r^2\text{ , where $r$ is its radius.}% notice the space between the opening brace and the comma.
\]

The area $A$ of a circle is given by $A=\pi r^2$, where $r$ is its radius.

\[
\text{The area }A\text{ of a circle is given by } A=\pi r^2\text{\kern-4pt , where $r$ is its radius.}% kerning inside mathmode
\]

The area $A$ of a circle is given by $A=\pi r^2$\kern-4pt, where $r$ is its radius.% kern outside of math mode

\[
V=\sum\int \mkern25mu \frac{4\pi r^3\!\mathop{}\mathrm dx}{3}% example of math kerning (command \mkern). 18 mu = 1 em
\]

\end{document}
```